# Japanese puzzle 2

Tags: language

My name is Stack reader.
Let's have a talk!

> こんぐらじゅれしょんず！　ゆうかんなうこみゅにけついんじゃぱにず。

Wait, you didn't understand me?
I thought I was speaking properly but I guess I still have to work on my pronunciation.
Can you really not understand what I tried to say?

Comment: google translate gave this-"Koncho rice Shozo! A citizen of Ukrainian capital".

Comment: @AmruthA yeah..... Google translate is the last thing you ever gonna want to use to translate Japanese to English :P

Comment: Funny thing about this puzzle is that some Japanese really talk like this when they try to talk english and are surprised if you don't understand them :)

Comment: @oleslaw hmmm, more people that understand Japanese than expected here lol.... I was expecting people to look up some form romanization and then reading it out loud to figure out how it sounds like but.... if someone can actually read it from the get go it's a bit too easy I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Japanese" text says:

> Kongurajureshonzu! Yuukannaukomyuniketsuinjapanizu.

Which sounds like a japanese person saying

> Congratulations! You can now communicate in Japanese.

Comment: Any explanations on how you came to that answer?

Comment: Umm.. I just read the text?

Comment: @Pokemon Be more specific and include it in the answer. It is not that obvious for most people.

Comment: updated my answer.